# Keep "ansible_ssh_common_args" variable secret

Tags: ssh, ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

My ansible playbook run through proxy but i want to keep this below variable secret from user who use my playbook vars:

```
"ansible_ssh_comoon_args:'-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@hostname""
```

Note: I dont want to keep the above variable either in inventory file or playbook or ansible.config file

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you aware you can set that through either ansible.cfg or the environment?

Comment: if I set environment it is visible directly to user in playbook. if I set in ansible.cfg it is visible to user indirectly i want more better way to completely invisible to user.

Comment: Ok, then put that proxy configuration in a ssh-config and reference that, which will keep the credentials out of `ps auwx` also

Comment: Do you mean to change config in /etc/ssh/ssh_config ? if yes can you please explain how to do the changes for proxy? this change has to effect only for ansible-playbook run not for any other SSH

Comment: `printf 'Host *\n  ProxyJump whatever@the-proxy-host\n' > /tmp/ansible-ssh-config; ansible -e ansible_ssh_common_args="-F /tmp/ansible-ssh-config" -m ping all`

Comment: I tried the above but didnt work even after replacing * with hostname the msg i got "[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only local is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all' "

Comment: It sounds like you are conflating the ssh-config, which unless you have some snowflake setup, really will be `Host *` for that setup (since the prior `ansible_ssh_common_args` attempt certainly didn't make exemptions for any host) with the `all` in my **example** command line. Since **you** didn't post the command you are using, it's not reasonable to expect anyone else to give you a working command line